# How can I get number from each id and append to another data attribute using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some listings.

Currently `id` is `test_3, test_1, test_2`. I need number `(3,1,2)` from `id` of each `li` and append this number in to another data attribute. Please check the result section. It will give you an idea about what I am expecting. Thanks

Html

```
<ul id="cat">
    <li id="test_3">Text 3</li>
    <li id="test_1">Text 1</li>
    <li id="test_2">Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

Script

```
$('#cat').attr('id').split("-")[2];
```

**Expected result**

```
<ul id="cat">
        <li id="test_3" data-id="3">Text 3</li>
        <li id="test_1" data-id="1">Text 1</li>
        <li id="test_2" data-id="2">Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all of the children of the `ul` element with the id `cat`.

On each loop, get the ID by getting the id attribute, splitting it on `_` and getting the first index.

You can then set the attribute by using JQuery's attribute function, which you can learn more about [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
$('#cat li').each(function () {
    var dataId = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    $(this).attr('data-id', dataId);
});
```

**An example of this in action**

```js
$('#cat li').each(function () {
    var dataId = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    $(this).attr('data-id', dataId);
});

console.log($('#cat').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="cat">
  <li id="test_3">Text 3</li>
  <li id="test_1">Text 1</li>
  <li id="test_2">Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can loop over the `li` elements and set the `data()` based on the number in the `id` attribute. Try this:

```js
$('#cat li').each(function() {
  $(this).data('id', this.id.split('_')[1]);
}).click(function() {
  console.log($(this).data('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="cat">
  <li id="test_3">Text 3</li>
  <li id="test_1">Text 1</li>
  <li id="test_2">Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should some your problem.

Using `$(this).attr("id").split('_')` will split "cat_3" into "cat" and "3" then using `[1]` after will select "3"

```js
$("#cat li").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("data-id", $(this).attr("id").split('_')[1]);
})

console.log($("#cat").html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="cat">
    <li id="test_3">Text 3</li>
    <li id="test_1">Text 1</li>
    <li id="test_2">Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a RegExpression.

```
var suffix = "test_2".match(/\d+/); // results --> 2
```

Basically it fetches out numeric value within a string value.

**Usage**

```
$('#cat li').each(function() {
  $(this).data('id', this.id.match(/\d+/));
})
```